# Does Xfce use Wayland?

Tags: x11, xfce, wayland

I'm confused. I'm using Xubuntu 22.04. Its desktop environment is Xfce, which, I think, uses X display server/protocol.

I tried to uninstall some Wayland packages from the system, for example "libwayland-server0". But the package manager warned that applications like VLC and Xfce-packages and even some X protocol-related packages would also be uninstalled. I didn't expect it.

Comment: You can test with the terminal command `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` if it is using X or Wayland. But even if 'only' X is used, it is possible that some Wayland package is bundled into Xubuntu, maybe because some part of it is used also when running X.

Comment: @sudodus, it's X11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some applications/libraries that XFCE uses support (read *are linked to*) both Xorg and Wayland hence removing Wayland support results in what you're seeing.

Comment: You mean, for example, GTK is linked to both X.org and Wayland libraries, but only calls X11 API subroutines in this case?

Comment: Yes, exactly...